# How does one split one column into two?

Tags: excel

I have a column in a Microsoft Excel document called "Full Name". I would like to take the first letter of each entity in the column and make a new column out of it. The rest of the name would also be another column.

For instance, the entity "Bob" would be split into "B" and "ob", respectively in two separate columns.

What is the most efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 5):

Using `=LEFT()` and `=RIGHT()`.

If A1 contains "Bob", put `=LEFT(A1,1)` in B1, and `=RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-1)` in cell C1.

Answer (score 4):

This is the absolute quickest way, and technically the only way, to do it (explanation below):

Select your column, then Data > Text to columns > Fixed width > Next > put a column separator between the first and second letter.

Note that this will actually split the column, like you specify in your question. So "Bob" will be gone forever, replaced by "B" and "ob". If you want to keep "Bob", then use worksheet formulas like in @Barry or @jonsca's answers.

Comment: Wow, thanks, this works without depending on the original column.

Answer (score 1):

Using formulas, for example, if `Bob` is in cell `A1` put this formula in `B1` : `=LEFT(A1,1)` and this formula in cell `C1` : `=MID(A1,2,LEN(A1)-1)`

Comment: RIGHT(A1, LEN(A1) - 1) will run slightly more effeciently than using MID, plus logically makes more sense.

Comment: I'll take your word on the efficiency but don't agree with you logically - I like to think from left to right.

Comment: Thanks! This works! I see, perhaps tail recursion kicks in when using RIGHT.